# Splitting 10Base-T between two cables

Tags: ethernet, cable

I have two CAT-5 cables running from a network/phone distribution box to a Telco box. Both cables are used for phone. One has 10Base-T in it. There is one pair in each available for use. Can I split up a 10Base-T signal between the two cables?

Comment: Why not move one of the telephone connections to another cable instead?

Comment: Face palm. Sometimes it takes someone not drilled into the issues to see the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might just-about be able to do this in a nonstandard way, but it does depend on the wiring you can't see.

You can have a 10 or 100 megabit connection on 2 pairs, using pins 1,2,3,6. (But not gigabit, and not POE).  Just google images search 2 pair Ethernet ( https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.-aOmrDy8LkRyrSIM6xi9tQHaFK%26pid%3DApi&f=1 for example) You can use any 2 cable pairs, but orange and green are traditional for this on Ethernet, and blue for phone line 1.

The gotcha is that phone cabling is very often daisy chained, which won't wor well (or at all) with Ethernet, so you will want to check that the cable is (or can be made to be) point-to-point.

Most modern pots/phone lines require 1 pair per line.

If its an option for the way your property has been cabled you may be better off repatching your phone cabling by using 2 pairs in 1 cable for phone, and the other cable for Ethernet. This will give you up to gigabit speeds (although cat5 is not rated for this - while cat5e is) and less issues with crosstalk/impedance differences from using 2 cables for different pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get adapters that take one ethernet cable and split it into one or more. You can also get a small ethernet switch and do it that way. Do you have any preference? Sorry I posted this as an answer, I can't comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

My unqualified guess is that it should work fine, as the Rx and Tx pairs are not supposed to interact with each other anyway. (Of course, a pair itself must not be split into individual wires.)

But even if it works, it's *incredibly* ugly to do something like this.

Instead, you could move one of the existing telephone connections from one cable to another. Now you have a cable with 2 spare pairs – a configuration which *is* known to be suitable for 10BASE-T.